# Multiple conditions during iteration, rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

So I have

```
  <% @invites.where(accept: 1).where(user_id: @user_id).each do |invite| %>
```

The idea is to only display the user in question, and where the accept value is equal to 1.

This causes the SQL query to be:

```
  SELECT `invites`.* FROM `invites` WHERE `invites`.`accept` = 0 AND `invites`.`user_id` IS NULL
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `.where(accept: 1, user_id: @user_id)`. Better would be `where(accepted: true, user: @user)` - ie use a boolean column and use the adjective form - accepted.

Comment: From your SQL generated I would guess that your ```accept``` does not accept integer values like 1(if it's a boolean type, you must pass ```true```), and that your ```@user_id``` is ```NULL```. Can you share with us your invites table schema and where you set the value for ```@user_id```?

Comment: This SQL can only be if you pass 0 (`where(accept: 0)`) AND if @user_id is `nil`. Your code is fine, the problem is in the values you pass. Make sure that @user_id is not `nil` and that you pass `accept: 0`, not `accept: 1`. Then you will get the wanted SQL.